# V4L2 FPS drops on android with more cores

Tags: android, arm, v4l2

I have three android devices Single core, Dual core and Quad core. I was able to make an app using v4l2 to grab the picture.

In standby mode all three devices are giving me 30FPS (as announced by camera hardware provider). But as soon as I start some processing on image and draw on canvas the FPS of Dual core and Quad core devices drops drastically. Single core device FPS reaches 28 which is acceptable but Dual core becomes 18 (on average) and Quad core 12.

I have used CPU performance governor in all three devices. Without performance mode FPS are even lower.
 *echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor*

Initially I thought it has something to do with customized linux kernel in android So,
I flashed PicUntu on quad core device but still I saw similar behavior in FPS drop. On Desktop with Windows and Ubuntu there is no such issue in the camera. I guess it has something to do with ARM.
Have anyone faced similar problem for UVC camera with V4L2 driver on android(ARM devices)? Is there any way to increase the FPS?

**EDIT ** Adding some more information**
For KitKat device if I bind my usb task to single core (taskset), FPS is improving by small factor. In kitkat overall performance is also better than Jelly bean.
I am not sure why usb speed suffers when the application goes to background even when overall cpu usage is small.

Comment: Does pinning the process to a single core with e.g. `taskset` make any difference?

Comment: Most likely this has to do with caches;  Some memory is being used on both CPUs.  By writing to similar lines, you will force the memory out to L2/L3 and this will drop performance.  For a single core, there is only one L1 cache, so they do not need to synchronize.  It may not be *you*, but a v4l driver or something else.  This is just a guess.  While your problem is interesting, I don't think we have enough information.

Comment: You need to set cpufreq governor per core. Make sure all cores are always online, and not getting turned on/off via some other mechanism. If you can guarantee those circumstances and still get same behavior, a profiling tools should just tell you what is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I tried various options. taskset (as suggested by Notlikethat) has no effect on Jelly bean or Picuntu but It improved the FPS on Kitkat. But it is still not as per expectation. cpufreq governor for all cores has no effect.